# how to calculate the other country time. using my local machine time in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, timezone

how to calculate the other country time. using my local machine time in c#?

Example:

My system having India time and my array contains  all the countries GMT time.

How to do the calculation to get the other country time?

if my time is 5.00 P.M if the country is Pakistan it should show 4.30 p.m

Comment: Hi Sir! I have the same problems with yours but seems I can't figure out how to put this in code.. I'm sorry if I don't get it I'm only a newbie in this thing getting 'UTC/GMT' of other country. If its ok with you, How can accomplish this using vb.net windowsForms? could you show the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you need to get the right [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) (e.g. by ID). From then on, it's fairly simple - I'd suggest that you use UTC wherever it's available, and probably `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime` as that's less ambiguous. Take your current time with [`DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow.aspx), get the appropriate time zone to convert to, and then use [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset, TimeZoneInfo)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765.aspx). That will get you the appropriate new `DateTimeOffset` (i.e. offset by the appropriate amount in the target time zone) which you can then format appropriately.

Comment: Hi Sir! I'm trying your answer but seems I can't figure out how to put this in code.. I'm sorry if I don't get it I'm only a newbie in this thing 'UTC/GMT'. How can accomplish this using vb.net windowsForms?

Comment: @Unknownymous: Well it's not clear exactly where you're stuck. Do you know the other time zone's ID, to start with?

Comment: In our office we use **(UTC -8:00) PACIFIC TIME (US & CANADA)** in local PC and I want to get the **Philippine standard time** which is (UTC/GMT +8 hours).. How can I accomplish that in vb.net winforms?

Comment: @Unknownymous: Well which bit are you having problems with? Just use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` (the local time zone is irrelevant) and call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` using the right `TimeZoneInfo` object. Which of those two calls do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure that your DateTime has DateTimeKind.Local (or is UTC with valid UTC time already). If it doesn't you can convert this:

```
myDate.SpecifyDateTimeKind(DateTimeKind.Local)
```

(Do it as close to where the date is created as possible; saves confusion later.)

Now find the timezone for the country you're interested in:

```
// In case you don't know what the key is:
var allTimeZones = TimeZone.GetSystemTimeZones();

// Then when you have the key:
var theirTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneKey);
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(myDateTime, theirTimeZone);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with what you can do is that you can write a function in which you can pass both the current time(of INDIA) and the time difference (in terms of +hrs:min or - hrs:min) . Your code can then compute the result and pass it back.

```
string time(string IndiaTime, string timeDifference) {
 string array1 = IndiaTime.split(':');
 // Over here I have considered you have passed the time in 24 hour format.
 int timeinMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(array1[0]) * 60 + Convert.ToInt32(array[1]);
 timeinMinutes = timeinMinutes + timeDifference;
 int minutes = time % 60;
 int hour = time / 60;
 If(hour > 24)
 hour = hour - 24;
 String finalTime = Convert.ToString(hour) + ":" + Convert.ToString(minutes);
 return finalTime;
}
```

Apart from this you can use various inbuilt C# classes as posted above.

Comment: You couldn't have described a worse way to do this if you tried. Using strings for both date and timeDifference :|